# upload image file to server in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

how can  I upload image to a server by giving its url.i tried this but it is not working.

```
    private void OnPhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            Uri u = new Uri("url here");

            wc.OpenWriteAsync(u, "POST", e.OriginalFileName);

        }
    }
```

Comment: he paha na...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938368/im-trying-to-send-a-picture-with-phonegap-on-wp8-but-im-getting-an-error

Comment: I did not understood the code here

Comment: mi just madat mhanun link pathawali malahi WP yett nahi